# Sending Pickled Objects Using Pickle5's Out-of-Band Buffers Over the Network

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle, zeromq

I've been using PyArrow to do my Serialization/Deserialization of custom made objects and have been searching for ways to use Pickle's new `protocol 5` to replace PyArrow as discussed [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/11239).

I want to send the serialized data of Pickle's new out-of-band buffer using a ZMQ socket to another ZMQ server. Here's an example code:

Server:

```
import numpy as np


class Person:
    def __init__(self, Thumbnail: np.ndarray = None):
        if Thumbnail is not None:
            self.Thumbnail: np.ndarray = Thumbnail
        else:
            self.Thumbnail: np.ndarray = np.random.rand(256, 256, 3)


def create_socket(ip, port, send_timeout=20000, receive_timeout=None):
    """
    :param ip: Server IP
    :param port: Server Port
    :param send_timeout: Send Timeout in MilliSeconds
    :param receive_timeout: Receive Timeout in MilliSeconds
    """
    import zmq

    try:
        print('Creating Socket @ tcp://%s:%s' % (ip, port))
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
        socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

        if send_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, send_timeout)
        if receive_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, receive_timeout)

        # Don't Linger Pending Messages As Soon As The Socket Is Closed
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)

        # Messages Will Be Queued ONLY For Completed Socket Connections
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1)

        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nCouldn't Create Socket on tcp://%s:%s => %s\n" % (ip, port, e))
        raise e


def connect_to_socket(ip, port, send_timeout=None, receive_timeout=None):
    import zmq

    try:
        print("Connecting to the Socket @ tcp://%s:%s" % (ip, port))
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (ip, port))

        if send_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, send_timeout)
        if receive_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, receive_timeout)

        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't Connect to Socket @ tcp://%s:%s", ip, port, e)
        raise e


server_socket = create_socket('localhost', 20000)

while True:
    data = server_socket.recv_multipart()
    print(data)
    server_socket.send_string("OK!")
```

Client:

```
import pickle

import numpy as np


class Person:
    def __init__(self, Thumbnail: np.ndarray = None):
        if Thumbnail is not None:
            self.Thumbnail: np.ndarray = Thumbnail
        else:
            self.Thumbnail: np.ndarray = np.random.rand(256, 256, 3)


def create_socket(ip, port, send_timeout=20000, receive_timeout=None):
    """
    :param ip: Server IP
    :param port: Server Port
    :param send_timeout: Send Timeout in MilliSeconds
    :param receive_timeout: Receive Timeout in MilliSeconds
    """
    import zmq

    try:
        print('Creating Socket @ tcp://%s:%s' % (ip, port))
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
        socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

        if send_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, send_timeout)
        if receive_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, receive_timeout)

        # Don't Linger Pending Messages As Soon As The Socket Is Closed
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)

        # Messages Will Be Queued ONLY For Completed Socket Connections
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1)

        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nCouldn't Create Socket on tcp://%s:%s => %s\n" % (ip, port, e))
        raise e


def connect_to_socket(ip, port, send_timeout=None, receive_timeout=None):
    import zmq

    try:
        print("Connecting to the Socket @ tcp://%s:%s" % (ip, port))
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (ip, port))

        if send_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, send_timeout)
        if receive_timeout is not None:
            socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, receive_timeout)

        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't Connect to Socket @ tcp://%s:%s", ip, port, e)
        raise e


PERSONS = [Person() for i in range(100)]

buffers = []
persons_pickled = pickle.dumps(PERSONS, protocol=5, buffer_callback=buffers.append)

socket_client = connect_to_socket('localhost', 20000)

while True:
    socket_client.send(persons_pickled)
    reply = socket_client.recv()
    print(reply)
```

I don't know how to send the two serialized objects (`persons_pickled` and `buffers`) without having to do any unnecessary memory copies. I don't want to have to send them as two separate `socket.send()` calls because that can introduce new problems down the line.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might indeed want multipart messages (your server seems willing to receive as such).

Send your `persons_pickled` and `buffers` in one go, using `send_multipart()`.

ZMQ will deliver both frames as a single message, or if something goes wrong neither are delivered. This means `persons_pickled` and `buffers` cannot be separated in transit (which is the problem I think you're trying to avoid).

At the receiving end you call recv_multipart. The first part gives you a `persons_pickled`, the second the corresponding `buffers`.

Comment: Thanks. How should I put them in the `send_multipart()` function? If it's like `send_multipart([persons_pickled, buffers])` then we'll have memory copies again (for putting the two parts inside a list) and the whole thing won't be any different from using PyArrow's approach.

Comment: Hmmm, I've realised that my naivety in Python has limited the value of my answer. Your `buffers` is going to be a list of `PickleBuffer`? I think that these could be used to make a new list of `zmq.Frame(buffer,copy=false)`. Then `send_multipart([persons_pickled, frames])` copies the Frame objects, but that doesn't involve copying the data. I think?!